# Given a word, how do I get the list of all words, that differ by one letter?

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have the word "CAT".  These words differ from "CAT" by one letter (not the full list)

- CUT
- CAP
- PAT
- FAT
- COT
- etc.

Is there an elegant way to generate this?  Obviously, one way to do it is through brute force.

pseduo code:

```
while (0 to length of word)
    while (A to Z)
        replace one letter at a time, and check if the resulting word is a valid word
```

If I had a 10 letter word, the loop would run 26 * 10 = 260 times.

Is there a better, elegant way to do this?

Comment: <pedantry>you'd only need 25*10 checks</pedantry>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given a list of words, for example with

```
words = set(line.strip().lower() for line in open('/usr/share/dict/words'))
```

you can build and index of "wildcarded" words, where you replace each character of the word with a wildcard (say "?"), so that for example "gat" and "fat" both get indexed to "?at":

```
def wildcard(s, idx):
    return s[:idx] + '?' + s[idx+1:]

def wildcarded(s):
    for idx in xrange(len(s)):
        yield wildcard(s, idx)

# list(wildcarded('cat')) returns ['?at', 'c?t', 'ca?']

from collections import defaultdict
index = defaultdict(list)

for word in words:
    for w in wildcarded(word):
        index[w].append(word)
```

Now if you want to look for all the words that differ by one letter from "cat", just look for "?at", "c?t" and "ca?" and concatenate the results:

```
def near_words(word):
    ret = []
    for w in wildcarded(word):
        ret += index[w]
    return ret

print near_words('cat')
# outputs ['cat', 'bat', 'zat', 'jat', 'kat', 'rat', 'sat', 'pat', 'hat', 'oat', 'gat', 'vat', 'nat', 'fat', 'lat', 'wat', 'eat', 'yat', 'mat', 'tat', 'cat', 'cut', 'cot', 'cit', 'cay', 'car', 'cap', 'caw', 'cat', 'can', 'cam', 'cal', 'cad', 'cab', 'cag']
print near_words('stack')
# outputs ['stack', 'stack', 'smack', 'spack', 'slack', 'snack', 'shack', 'swack', 'stuck', 'stack', 'stick', 'stock', 'stank', 'stack', 'stark', 'stauk', 'stalk', 'stack']
```

If the maximum word length is `L` and the number of words is `N`, the index is made of `O(NL)` pointers, while the lookup algorithm runs in time `O(L + number of results)`.

If you want to look for all the words that differ by `K` letters instead of `1` this approach doesn't generalize well, but it is a very hard problem in full generality (it is the problem of finding neighbors in Hamming spaces).

Answer (score 3):

1. Work out what your performance requirements really are.
2. Implement it exactly as you described it above.
3. Time it, and see if you meet those requirements already.
4. Optimise only if required (and I am willing to bet it isn't required, because 260 look-ups in a hash table of words that fit in RAM isn't that slow.)

Comment: CAT is just an example. When the word is made of more letters we are wasting time with non-existent words.

Comment: 250 hash lookups won't take any time

Comment: Yes, @Dialecticus. CAT would only take 78 look-ups. It takes 10 letters to take it all the way up to (gulp) 260. :-) I don't know the performance requirements, but I strongly suspect that the naive implementation would meet any reasonable ones.

Answer (score 2):

The size of a dictionary for a human-language and a word length are tiny (~10**5 and ~100), therefore a brute-force approach will do unless measurements shows otherwise in your case:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string

ALL_WORDS = set(open('/usr/share/dict/words').read().lower().split())
ALPHABET = string.ascii_lowercase

def known(words): return set(w for w in words if w in ALL_WORDS)

def one_letter(word):
    # http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html
    splits = ((word[:i], word[i:]) for i in range(len(word) + 1))
    replaces  = (a + c + b[1:] for a, b in splits for c in ALPHABET if b)
    return set(replaces)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(known(one_letter("cat")))
```

#### Output

```py
set(['bat',
     'cab',
     'cad',
     'cal',
     'cam',
     'can',
     'cap',
     'car',
     'cat',
     'caw',
     'cot',
     'cut',
     'eat',
     'fat',
     'hat',
     'mat',
     'nat',
     'oat',
     'pat',
     'rat',
     'sat',
     'tat',
     'vat'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a dictionary of valid words to check against, or otherwise the problem isn't going to generate "words" but "strings" rather. There are many available for free online, or if you're on Linux most distros ship with dictionary files in `/usr/share/dict/`.

There are two approaches to take:

1. For each letter in the word, replace it with all other 25 characters and check if it's in the dictionary. Use a hashtable to store the dictionary words for efficient querying. You only need to populate the hashtable with words of the same length as your search word. This will be O(MN + 25N) = O(MN), where M is the number of words of length N in your dictionary and N is the length of your word.
2. For each dictionary word that is the same length as your search word, check how many characters differ. This will be O(MN).

Although both fall into the same complexity class, the latter drops the O(25N) term and overhead associated with a hashtable.

Comment: Both of which, would involve replacing one letter at a time.  This is similar to the pseudo code, correct?

Comment: @user The first solution replaces so is similar in that regard. The second solution counts changes.

Answer (score 1):

For: l = word length, w = number of words in wordlist:

Your algorithm is O(l.(l log w)) for a tree wordlist, *plus* the cost of constructing the wordlist in the first place (which is O(w log (w))) (I assume a tree here, you can redo this with a hash if you like).

This is O(l.w)

As another answer already suggests, you don't care that the word has an a, b or z in place of the character you want to change, you just care that it's not the letter that you started with.  So test the one combination you don't want, rather than all of the combinations that would do.

So:

```
for(each candidate word from the wordlist) {
  difference = 0
  for(each letter in your original word) {
    does it match? if not, difference++
  }
  if difference = 1, store the candidate word as a solution
}
```

Now, you're going to argue that you're looking at 78 comparisons versus thousands, but that's not accurate: in order to make use of a wordlist to see if a candidate is available, your method involves creating a content-addressed structure (a tree or hash) before you even start, plus the lookups into the hash once you're running.  The solution above also allows you to read the wordlist file once per word under test (without having to hold it in memory for rescanning).  Your solution is probably faster for doing this on many words at once, but the above is better for a single word lookup, and more memory efficient in every case.

Credit to other answers for the 'count the difference' method of spotting word differences...

Comment: "The solution above *allows* you to read the wordlist file once per word."  Nice, um, *feature* there.  :-P

Comment: Changed for the benefit of the peanut gallery ;)

Comment: Fair enough <grudgingly hands over the +1> ;)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you'll need to iterate through all letters to check it. But the another approach would be to check dictionary for words, which corresponds to mask ?AT, C?T, CA? (where ? can be every symbol)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Checking for the mask, isn't it the same as my pseudo code?

Comment: No, but it is probably going to be much slower, as you will be looking at every word in the dictionary k times (where K is the number of letters in the word)

Comment: It's kinda reversed version of your algorithm, it searches for suitables words in dictionary, while your iterates through all words and checks if this word is available in dictionary. Depending on dictionary size/word size one or another can be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings always match in length one way would be to remove one letter at a time and compare result on both strings, 10 chars would be 10 loops.

regards,
/t

Comment: I think this would be less efficient than replacing one letter at a time, assuming we have a database of all the words.  For example, if we had 1000 three letter words, this would involve 1000 * 3 = 3000 comparisons.  But if we replace one letter at a time, it would be 26 * 3 = 78.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the word list and for each word count the different letter. If the count becomes greater than 1 go to next word.

Faster solution, if dictionary is static and there are plenty of words to check: create a matrix of letters. Rows are first letter in the word, columns are second letter in the word. Cells are list of words that begin with given first and second letter. When you want to find similar words of a given word then iterate through just one row and then just one column. If not on intersecting cell the all other letters of every iterated word must match. On intersecting cell one letter must be different.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to optimise the run-time (and I still say you probably don't need to in any reasonable performance situation) then go through the dictionary once, and run your algorithm on every word.

Create a map from the corrupted words to a list of each of the corresponding correctly spelled words.

I estimate that the 20,000 words, processing at least 30 a second, will take no more than 11 minutes to process.

Store the resulting hash table on disk, and load it into memory when required. Then perform the processing by simply looking up the input words in the hash table and find the corresponding list of correctly-spelled words.

Memory intensive, but super-fast - and if you are worried about the performance of 260 look-ups, you must be dealing with tens of thousands of words, and a solution like this is probably the best you'll get.